# Don't know how to create ISeq from: Java.lang.Long

Tags: java, casting, clojure, sequence, read-eval-print-loop

Doing some practice on recursion and map implementation to knock some rust off Clojure. I'm using lists only here so how am I trying to mix seq and non-seqable stuff?

```
(defn mapset
  ([operator operand] (mapset operator operand '()))
  ([operator operand finished-set]
   (if (empty? operand)
     '(finished-set)
     (mapset operator (rest operand) (into finished-set (operator (first operand)))))))
```

REPL:

```
namespace.name> (mapset + '(1 3 4 6 5))
Execution error (IllegalArgumentException) at tester.core/mapset (core.clj:38).
Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some errors:

- replace `'(finished-set)` with `finished-set`
- [`into`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/into) adds elements from one collection to another, I think you're looking for [`conj`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/conj) (that's the source of `IllegalArgumentException`)
- and if you'll use `conj`, you have to use `[]` as initial `finished-set`, because `conj` adds element to beginning of the list, but at the end of the vector

Your function, with minimal changes:

```
(defn mapset
  ([operator operand] (mapset operator operand []))
  ([operator operand finished-set]
   (if (empty? operand)
     finished-set
     (mapset operator (rest operand) (conj finished-set (operator (first operand)))))))
```

Tests:

```
(mapset inc '(1 3 4 6 5))
; => [2 4 5 7 6]

(mapset dec '(1 3 4 6 5))
; => [0 2 3 5 4]
```

You can also write it with only two arguments, using [`cons`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/cons):

```
(defn mapset [operator operand]
  (if (empty? operand) 
    '()
    (cons (operator (first operand))
          (mapset operator (rest operand)))))
```

Note that neither version is lazy, that would require adding [`lazy-seq`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/lazy-seq).

Comment: Bravo! It worked. Interestingly, while trying to fix the errors, I got to the code that you pasted (I actually double checked by regressing the code back a few steps and, yup there it is). The ONLY difference was that the return after the empty? check was in parenthesis. That got me "Execution error (ArityException) at tester.core/mapset (core.clj:37). Wrong number of args (0) passed to: clojure.lang.PersistentVector         Do you know what caused this?

Answer (score 0):

This error means you are are accidentally giving it an integer when it is expecting a sequence (list, vector, etc):

```
demo.core=> (first 5)
Execution error (IllegalArgumentException) at demo.core/eval2055 (form-init5218243389029929734.clj:1).
Don't know how to create ISeq from: java.lang.Long
```

Comment: You put it more eloquently then I could. I suspected that as one possible reason but I didn't know for sure. In future, I'll keep this in mind.